Finite element accuracy on non-affine quadrilateral meshes
I have a simple finite element code (continuous Galerkin method, $Q_1$ tensor product spaces) for $-\Delta \psi = f$ on the unit square with essential boundary conditions. I want to claim that for any $\psi\in Q_1$, the finite element method in theory gives  $\psi_h=\psi$ (and thus a finite element code would give similar outcomes). Am I incorrect here? I did some reading about finite element approximation on quad meshings (Finite element approximation on quadrilateral meshes), but this looks to be specific to serendipity/mixed finite elements?
To check the code, I use a few types of meshings for the unit square, and a couple analytic solutions. Generally, I see errors like $\||\psi - \psi_h\||_{L^2}= O(h^2)$, but the code is giving confusing results when non-affine quadrilateral meshings are used.

If I set $\psi = 1 + x + y + xy \in Q_1$, and use a mesh of square elements, the code gives $\psi_h$ which satisfies $\||\psi - \psi_h\||_{L^2} = 10^{-13}$.
If I set $\psi = 1 + x + y \in Q_1$, and use a mesh of general quadrilaterals (each quad is convex/shape regular), the code gives $\psi_h$ which satisfies $\||\psi - \psi_h\||_{L^2} = 10^{-13}$.
If I set $\psi = 1 + x + y + xy\in Q_1$, and use a mesh of general quadrilaterals (each quad is convex/shape regular),the code gives $\psi_h$ that satisfies $\||\psi - \psi_h\||_{L^2} = 10^{-5}$.



What do you mean by "non-affine quadrilateral meshes"? Also, the absolute errors are mesh dependent and problem dependent, want people normally compare is how that works changes in a sequence of meshes with $h \rightarrow 0$.

By "non-affine quadrilateral meshes" I mean a conforming mesh consisting of all straight sided quadrilaterals (I've attached a photo), but some are not parallelograms. I do generally observe that the errors for this simple problem decay at the expected rates. What I find odd is when I do the same computations for "P1" continuous Galerkin (3 node triangular unstructured mesh), and the exact solution is a polynomial $\psi=1+x+y$, the errors are "zero" up to round-off. I was anticipating that Q1 continuous FEM would be able to capture the exact degree one polynomial solution.

Case of quad meshes
Let us take exact solution to be $\psi = 1 + x + y + xy$. Then $\psi$ satisfies
$$
a(\psi,\phi) = 0, \qquad \forall \phi \in H^1_0
$$
with $\psi$ taking prescribed boundary values.
In the FEM you are solving for $\psi_h$
$$
a_h(\psi_h, \phi_h) =0, \qquad \forall \phi_h \in V_h\cap C_0
$$
with $\psi_h = \psi$ on the boundary. Here $V_h \subset H^1$ is the FE piecewise polynomial space and $C_0$ is space of continuous functions vanishing on the boundary.
I write $a_h(\cdot,\cdot)$ since this involves integrals which are approximated by quadratures, and on general quad meshes, the quadratures will not be exact due to presence of jacobian terms that are non-polynomial. The Jacobians arise because you map a general quad to a unit square to construct your FE polynomials. Though the map is bilinear, you get determinant of jacobian in the integrals which are not just polynomial functions for general quad elements.
Now on a quad mesh of rectangles, the map is affine, the quadratures can be exact and so the FE solution satisfies
$$
a(\psi_h, \phi_h) =0, \qquad \forall \phi_h \in V_h\cap C_0
$$
and the exact solution also satisfies
$$
a(\psi, \phi_h) =0, \qquad \forall \phi_h \in V_h\cap C_0
$$
Subtracting the two
$$
a(\psi_h-\psi, \phi_h) =0, \qquad \forall \phi_h \in V_h\cap C_0
$$
with $\psi_h - \psi = 0$ on the boundary.
This can also be written as
$$
a(\psi_h-I_h \psi, \phi_h) =0, \qquad \forall \phi_h \in V_h\cap C_0
$$
with $\psi_h - I_h \psi = 0$ on the boundary, where $I_h$ is the interpolation to the FE space, and since $I_h \psi = \psi$ for this particular solution.
By the existence/uniqueness of FE solution
$$
\psi_h - I_h \psi = 0 \qquad\implies\qquad \psi_h = I_h \psi = \psi
$$
and you are observing machine precision errors on rectangular grids.
The above proof cannot be done on general quad meshes since $a_h \ne a$.

This makes more sense now!
